# Closing Datepicker window with out hide method

Tags: datepicker

How to close Datepicker window without hide or using css. I am able to close through hide()  but it doesnt behave like a datepicker control any longer, meaning datepicker window doesnt pop on clicking it again.

I have tried javascript method hide() but doesnt work as I expected